# Как сделать Redirect в gorilla mux golang?

Tags: api, golang, redirect

Пишу API сервер и столкнулся с проблемой редиректа. Можете написать пример, как сделать редирект с помощью библиотеки gorilla?

Answer (score 0):

[англоязычная версия сайта с вопросом и ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616975/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-in-gorilla-mux) по данной теме

```
func RedirectToHTTPSRouter(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
      return http.HandlerFunc(func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
      proto := req.Header.Get("x-forwarded-proto")
      if proto == "http" || proto == "HTTP" {
          http.Redirect(res, req, fmt.Sprintf("https://%s%s", req.Host, req.URL), 
          http.StatusPermanentRedirect)
          return
      }

      next.ServeHTTP(res, req)

    })
}

func main() {

     router := mux.NewRouter()

     httpsRouter := RedirectToHTTPSRouter(router)

     log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(lib.Settings.Address, httpsRouter))

}
```